# How to use java-melody with SOLR 5?

Tags: solr, monitoring, solr5, java-melody

Solr 5 is not `war` anymore. Is there a correct way to use `java-melody` with Solr 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install guide for java melody says you can use [web.xml method](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#2-webxml-file) instead.

You can find the web.xml file for Solr 5.3 in *server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF* of the installation.

Comment: I checked it - it works - just copy `javamelody.jar`, `jrobin-x.jar` jars to `./lib` directory and update `web.xml`